# Spark ML Word2Vec Serialization Issues

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Spark Version: 1.6.1

I have recently refactored our Word2Vec code to move to DataFrame based ml models, but I am having problem in serializing and loading the model locally.

I am able to successfully:

1. Fit the dataframe and create the model.
2. Retrieve synonyms.

When I try to serialize the model locally, vectors are not serialized and hence the size of the file is too small approx 2K for 10GB of data.

```
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/word2vec");
        ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
        so.writeObject(word2VecModel);
        so.flush();
        so.close();
        logger.info("Word2Vec model saved");
```

On loading the model and calling the findSynonyms() function results in below exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2VecModel.transform(Word2Vec.scala:224)

Is there a way to save the model locally ?

Comment: Does the directory /tmp/word2vec already exist?

Comment: yes the dir /tmp exists and word2vec is the name of the file for model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [Model Persistence functionality](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/31/apache-spark-2-0-preview-machine-learning-model-persistence.html) that is included now out-of-the-box? You can either save separate model, whole pipeline, etc. I had tried that and that worked.